# How does C++ Nifty Counter idiom guarantee both static initialization and static deinitialization

Tags: c++, static-order-fiasco

While learning from isocpp, I came across an [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#nifty-counter-idiom). Which says: "What is a technique to guarantee both static initialization and static deinitialization?" And the short answer is just hinted out:

> Short answer: use the Nifty Counter Idiom (but make sure you
> understand the non-trivial tradeoffs!).

Till now, I can't understand what does [Nifty Counter Idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) mean and how it fixes the Fiasco problem. I am already aware of [Construct On First Use Idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use), and its side effects while using a static object or a static pointer (wrapped in a global function returning reference)

Here's a simple example actually prone to a Fiasco problem:

```
//x.cpp
include "x.hpp" // struct X { X(int); void f(); };

X x{ 10 };
struct Y { Y(); };
Y::Y(){ x.f(); };

//y.cpp
include <iostream>
include "y.hpp" // struct Y { Y(); };

struct X { X(int); void f(); private: int _x; };
X::X(int i) { _x = i; }; 
void X::f() { std::cout << _x << std::endl; };
Y y;
```

From [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter), it's mentioned the main use of Nifty Counter Idiom

> Intent: Ensure a non-local static object is initialized before its
> first use and destroyed only after last use of the object.

Now what I need now is, how does *Nifty Counter Idiom* specifically can solve both static order initialization and deinitialization in the above code, regardless of other workarounds as `constinit`. Given that the above program is compiled like this:

`~$ g++ x.cpp y.cpp && ./a.out` >> **10**

`~$ g++ y.cpp x.cpp && ./a.out` >> **0**

Comment: The compiler is responsible for generating code to ensure that global objects are destroyed in reverse order of their construction.

Comment: @PeteBecker, That's fine, but what does that have to do with what I am asking for? This my question **"How does C++ Nifty Counter idiom guarantee both static initialization and static deinitialization"**

Comment: It's exactly the answer to the part about destruction: nifty counter or otherwise, the compiler is responsible. If you want to know about how the compiler does that (there are several different things that lead to indeterminate order of construction) then you can ask that, but you probably won't get a satisfactory answer, because it's deep in implementation details.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do you understand how it ensures 'constructed at/before first use'?  The [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) you provide seems fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: @PeteBecker Per my understanding, fiasco problem can possibly be avoided using  Construct On First Use Idiom by wrapping the static object in a global function, that's all about Construct On First Use Idiom. Similarly, according to the [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter), (which says: **Intent: Ensure a non-local static object is initialized before its first use and destroyed only after last use of the object.**), how can Nifty Counter idiom does the same thing, how it can prevent fiasco like  Construct On First Use Idiom? how this happen in **code**?

Comment: @PeteBecker, I can, in my example above, wrap the object `x{ 10 }` in a global function and that's fine since I have used CONFU idiom, Now, *by using nifty idiom*, what's the approach it follows to do what's the CONFU idiom does? is wrapping the object in a function?  is wrapping the object in a class? or what? I hope you now understand what I mean.

Comment: @G.M. I think that my question is straightforward: "how does Nifty Counter Idiom specifically can solve both static order initialization and deinitialization in the above code".  Or does it have nothing to do, *in code*, with what CONFU idiom is doing? that's why I also said: "Till now, I can't understand what does Nifty Counter Idiom mean and how it fixes the Fiasco problem"

Comment: @G.M. The link that you said is fairly self-explanatory provides an example, *maybe* (for me), has nothing to do with what I am asking for; that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: @AccessDenied: "*has nothing to do with what I am asking for;*" The link explains, in some detail, how it solves the problem you're talking about. Perhaps you could explain what part of that description confuses you?

Comment: @NicolBolas. My problem is not in the description or even the example they provided. I just need to somehow use Nifty Counter Idiom to solve Fiasco **in my simple example above**

Comment: @AccessDenied: So... you're just asking people to write code for you? I mean, if you understand the principles of the idiom, then it should be fairly clear how to go about applying them(step 1 would be to stop doing silly things like defining members of one class in the .cpp file for a different one. Once you fix where your code goes, you'll find that the solution presents itself). At the very least, you could explain why you're having trouble applying those principles.

Comment: @AccessDenied oh, so when you say "has nothing to do with what I am asking for" you meant you don't care that it explains the concept so that you can easily apply it to your specific case, you want us to write the code for you for your class, you couldn't care less about understanding the idiom (even thought that's what you asked). That's honestly sad, but at least the answers here will help other people.

Comment: First off, respecting your replay; *"step 1 would be to stop doing silly things like defining members of one class in the .cpp file for a different one"*; that's a problem maybe you and I facing in our code; so you don't have to avoid using problematic stuff in your code as long as there is already a solution to your problem, it depends on your requirements. *"you're just asking people to write code for you?"* Don't take me literally, I just provide a simple example to generalize the workaround and make the solution portable for others

Comment: @bolov, "has nothing to do with what I am asking for", I said that because I can't just reflect the solution they provided to my example, it's not so long example to force peoples to write code for me, I just need the approach of how the solution solves the problem,

Comment: @AccessDenied: You keep saying "how the solution solves the problem", but that's asking for a *description*, not "change my code so that it uses this idiom".

Comment: @AccessDenied: "*I can't just reflect the solution they provided to my example*" Well, yeah. Most people `extern` variables to code that needs to use them. You have instead chosen to move the *code* to the file where that variable gets declared. That makes the idiom more difficult to use if you're not willing to move the code back to where it's supposed to be.

Comment: @AccessDenied you appear to be fluent in english but there is clearly a communication barrier here. You say one thing and mean the opposite. You say "has nothing to do with" about an article that is exactly about this. You ask "how does the idiom work" but you mean "write code".

Comment: @bolov, yeah sorry, that's true, I am not good in English, English is not my main language, that's maybe others can't fully understand what I exactly mean.

Answer (score 4):

I think the link you provided explains it pretty well. But here's my attempt at it.

### First what is the problem

```
// stream.hpp

struct Stream {
  Stream ();
  ~Stream ();
  void operator<<(int);
};

extern Stream stream; // global stream object
```

```
// stream.cpp

#include "stream.hpp"

Stream::Stream () { /* initialize things */ }
Stream::~Stream () { /* clean up */ }
void Stream::operator<<(int a) { /* write to stream */ }

Stream stream{};
```

```
// app.cpp

#include "stream.hpp"

struct X
{
    X()
    {
         stream << 24; // use stream object
    }
    ~X()
    {
         stream << 1024; // use stream object
    }

};

X x{}; // in this static initialization the static stream object is used
```

The C++ standard does not guarantee any order of initialization of static objects across TUs. `stream` and `x` are in different TUs, so `stream` could be initialized first, which is fine. Or `x` could be initialized before `stream` which is bad because the initialization of `x` uses `stream` which is not initialized yet.

The same problem happens for destructors if `stream` is destructed before `x`.

### The nifty counter solution

It leverages the fact that in a TU objects are initialized and destructed in order. But we can't have a `stream` object for every TU, so we use a trick, we instead use a `StreamInitializer` object for every TU. This `streamInitializer` will be constructed before `x` and destructed after `x` and we make sure that only the first `streamInitializer` that gets constructed creates the stream object and only the last `streamInitializer` to be destructed destroys the stream object:

```
// stream.hpp

struct Stream {
  Stream ();
  ~Stream ();
  void operator<<(int);
};
extern Stream& stream; // global stream object

struct StreamInitializer {
  StreamInitializer ();
  ~StreamInitializer ();
};

static StreamInitializer streamInitializer{}; // static initializer for every TU
```

```
// stream.cpp

#include "stream.hpp"

static int nifty_counter{}; // zero initialized at load time
static typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof (Stream), alignof (Stream)>::type
  stream_buf; // memory for the stream object
Stream& stream = reinterpret_cast<Stream&> (stream_buf);

Stream::Stream () { // initialize things }
Stream::~Stream () { // clean-up } 

StreamInitializer::StreamInitializer ()
{
  if (nifty_counter++ == 0) new (&stream) Stream (); // placement new
}
StreamInitializer::~StreamInitializer ()
{
  if (--nifty_counter == 0) (&stream)->~Stream ();
}
```

Our app.cpp is the same

```
// app.cpp

#include "stream.hpp"

struct X
{
    X()
    {
        stream << 24; // use stream object
    }
    ~X()
    {
         stream << 1024; // use stream object
    }

};

X x{}; // in this static initialization the static stream object is used
```

Now `stream` is not a value, it's a reference. So in this line `Stream& stream = reinterpret_cast<Stream&> (stream_buf);` no `Stream` object is created. Just the reference is bound to the still non existing object residing at the `stream_buf` memory. This object will be constructed later.

Every compilation unit has a `streamInitializer` object. Those objects initialize in any order, but it doesn't matter because on only one of them `nifty_counter` will be `0` and on that and only on that one the line `new (&stream) Stream ();` is executed. This line actually creates the `stream` object at the memory location `stream_buf`.

Now why is the line `X x{};` ok in this scenario? Because this TU's `streamInitializer` object is initialized before `x`, which ensures that `stream` is initialized before `x`. This is true for every TU where `stream.hpp` is correctly included before any use of the `stream` object.

The same logic applies to the destructor, but in reverse order.

### Recap

Static objects in different TU can be initialized in any order. This is a problem if one static object from one TU uses in it's constructor or destructor another static object from another TU.

In a TU object are constructed and destructed in order.

In the nifty connter idiom:

- one TU holds a raw memory for the stream object
- `stream` is a reference to the object at that memory location
- a `streamInitializer` object is created in every every TU that uses the `stream` object.
- only 1 `streamInitializer` will create the stream object, the 1st that is initialized
- in a TU before every use of `x` at least the `streamInitializer` in that TU is already initialized. This means that at least one `streamInitializer` was constructed, this means that `stream` is constructed before the constructor of `x`.

---

*include guards omitted for brevity*

Comment: Looking at the the Nifty counter solution, I'm trying to understand why can the `StreamInitializer` constructor use the `nifty_counter` and `stream` variables. By [Ordered dynamic initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Static_initialization), dynamic initialization of `streamInitializer` variable should occur the first in `stream.cpp` TSU. So I would guess both `nifty_counter` and `stream` variables get initialized by static initialization which must occur at compile time. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that *is* a nifty counter mechanism.  It doesn't "fix" the ordering-fiasco; rather, what it is doing is using an integer counter to make it so that the (still undefined) order in which the compiler does its static-initialization and static-destruction *doesn't matter*.

How does it do that?  Simple; no matter which `StreamInitializer` object's static-initialization happens first, the first thing the `StreamInitializer()` constructor will do is increment `nifty_counter`.  Since `nifty_counter` was default-initialized to zero, that means the `if (nifty_counter++ == 0)` test in the constructor will return true only once, the first time it is executed, *regardless of which .cpp file the initialization is being triggered from*.  That will cause the placement-new initialization of the `Stream` object to happen exactly once, as a side-effect of the first `StreamInitializer` being initialized.

Similarly, each `~StreamInitializer()` destructor will decrement `nifty_count`, and since there will be exactly the same number of `~StreamInitializer()` destructor-calls (at the end of the program's execution) as there were `StreamInitializer()` constructor-calls (at the beginning of the program's execution), we are guaranteed that it will be the very last call to `~StreamInitializer()` that decrements `nifty_counter` back to zero.  That will be true *regardless of the order that the compiler chooses for destruction to happen*, which means that the destruction of the `Stream` object will occur only during the last `~StreamInitializer()` call, which is what you want.

The upshot is that as long as your .cpp file declares a `StreamInitializer` object first, it can safely access the `Stream` object, because the presence of a valid `StreamInitializer` object (and in particular, the execution of its constructor and destructor at the appropriate times) guarantees that the `Stream` object will be valid in any subsequent static-object-constructor/destructor code in that .cpp file.